# Invoke COM object in a "PostMessage" manner

Tags: winapi, com, com+, dcom

I have an STA thread in which I am currently executing some operation. Due to limitations of the environment (Office), there are certain things that I cannot do at this point in time. However, I can do these things immediately after the current message pump cycle is complete.

I would normally do this with my own message-only window handle to which I would post a message using PostMessage. However, given the environment and the architecture at hand, it is critical that the operation be queued alongside other COM object invocations coming from other threads/processes. Or in more exact terms, the post-invoke operations will need to be executed during a [CoWaitForMultipleHandles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680732.aspx) call.

Does COM(+) provide a mechanism for invoking a method "later"? Other than:

- Create a thread myself (or otherwise reuse a thread I have created myself). Make it an STA thread. Marshal my object interface to that thread. Use ICallFactory to create a call object for my async interface. Fire and forget from this secondary thread.
- Create an MTA object strictly for the postback (the target COM server is still an STA object on the original STA thread). When instantiated, COM will create a thread for me. Call to that MTA object to schedule the postback (using the same ICallFactory method as before).
- Dig out the COM dispatcher window handle and PostMessage to it.

The first two require a separate thread, which seems undesirable. The last is a hack.

Comment: Pretty unclear what "current message pump cycle" could mean.  If you need something to happen later then the simplest and least risky way is to use SetTimer().

Comment: SetTimer would require my own WndProc, which I would get either by creating my own window (messages for which won't be processed in CoWaitForMultipleHandles) or overriding WndProc of the com dispatcher window (a hack).

Comment: [Making and Processing Asynchronous Calls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: As far as I know, this is for making async calls between apartments. At least, as implemented by the available frameworks (for example, the proxy/stub generated from IDL has ICallFactory support baked in).

Comment: I could certainly implement it myself, but the implementation of my call objects would have to use one of the bulleted techniques from my post, so nothing is gained.

Comment: With what arguments is `CoWaitForMultipleHandles` being called?  If it includes the `COWAIT_DISPATCH_WINDOW_MESSAGES` flag in the first parameter, you can actually `PostMessage` to your message-only window.  Otherwise, you'll need to make a call to the current apartment from another apartment.  I guess queuing work on a thread pool (MTA) would be the most efficient way, if you already have a thread pool.  Either way, you have to synchronization guarantee that your call is made before or after `CWFMH` returns.

Comment: Unfortunately, COWAIT_DISPATCH_WINDOW_MESSAGES dispatches all window messages from all handles. This is happening within the context of an Office application, and allowing all messages to be processed means the host application will be responding in ways that it should not. Also, COWAIT_DISPATCH_WINDOW_MESSAGES isn't available on XP, which is unfortunately our baseline for client support.

Comment: Do you create that STA thread, or is it one of the Office own thread?

Comment: It's one of Office's threads.

Comment: @MichaelGunter, what are you specifically trying to achieve?  What case requires you to *do these things immediately after the current message pump cycle is complete*?  What kind of things are these, and what is the current message pump cycle?

Comment: It's a common problem with Office automation that the application is not in an automatable state when automation needs to occur. I am hoping to be able to defer this automation until "as soon as possible after now." I have achieved this in the past with a combination of PostMessage (as soon as possible) and a timer (fallback for when PostMessage wasn't enough). I am looking for an option to replace the PostMessage part. And yes, your point about the current message pump cycle is valid, since I cannot control whether I'm in a nested pump or the root one owned by the Office product.

Answer (score 0):

Below are a few hacks to try. I haven't tried them myself in respect to `CoWaitForMultipleHandles`, so I'm not sure if any of them would work in your hosted Office environment:

- Office provides an [`IMsoComponentManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff518963(v=office.12).aspx) service. You'd implement [`IMsoComponent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff518955(v=office.12).aspx) (check [this](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComponentManagerBroker.cs) for some sample code). Hopefully, `IMsoComponent::FDoIdle` could be useful.
- [`SetTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx) can accept `TIMERPROC lpTimerFunc`. You don't have to create a window for that to work, you can use ATL thunks or a similar technique to create a C++ closure. I've done this with `SetTimer` and it works, but again I'm not sure if it works with `CoWaitForMultipleHandles` because the the timer callback normally gets invoked inside `DispatchMessage`. Besides, [timer gets low priority in message dispatching](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/96006), so it may be out of sequence.
- [`WH_FOREGROUNDIDLE/ForegroundIdleProc`](http://WH_FOREGROUNDIDLE/ForegroundIdleProc) might be interesting, using an ATL thunk. It should be called from inside `CoWaitForMultipleHandles`, too, when the latter is idle.
- See if a custom [COM message filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693324(v=vs.85).aspx) on your STA thread can be useful. **Updated**, you clarified it's an Office thread, so most likely it has its own COM message filter. Perhaps, you can override it for the scope of your call.
- See if implementing [`IAdviseSink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692513(v=vs.85).aspx) on your object can be useful. This interface is AFAIK the *only* exception to the COM rules in that its methods are called *asynchronously* when invoked via a COM proxy from another apartment. Perhaps, this would be best bet in solving your problem.
- **Updated**, now that we know for sure you're running on a MSO STA thread, there's another hack. You can start a nested modal message loop, for the scope of your call. Then you can have control over each message pump cycle. This is a `DoEvents`-style hack I wouldn't normally recommend, but you're already in a hack zone. You'd at least need to do disable the Office UI (for the scope of the call) to limit the chance for re-entrancy. Then you'd initiate the nested message loop with `IMsoComponentManager::FPushMessageLoop` with `msoloopDoEvents` and expect `IMsoComponent::FContinueMessageLoop` to be called back upon each new iteration (pump).

Comment: Is IMsoComponentManager deprecated? (Not necessarily a deal breaker, but...)

Comment: @MichaelGunter, it's supported in all recent version of the Office, including 2013. It's also used by .NET for hosted .NET office components/extensions. I'm sure it isn't going anywhere anytime soon.

Comment: I wonder why this information is so hard to find. The docs for 2010+ don't come up immediately when searching. I did manage to find the docs for Office 2010, but no documentation seems to exist for Office 2013. I agree this isn't going anywhere, but it is curious.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg702942(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Where can I find the definitions of these interfaces? Are they in a type library somewhere? They aren't in mso.dll.

Comment: It's been quiet a long while since I used these interfaces. There was indeed an .H file but I don't have it anymore and I can't trace its origins. Once thing I remember though, another name for `IMsoComponentManage` is `IOleComponentManager`, try searching for it. Worst case, you can adapt a C# version from [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/UnsafeNativeMethods.cs,1e422f359f1afdbe).